# Simplify code for getting multiple disease proportions in the population

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, bind

I have data which looks like this

```
df <- data.frame (
cancer = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
CVD =    c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
diab =   c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
stroke = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
asthma = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
LTC_count = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0))
```

My data is much larger, approx. 1 million rows. Each row is a person, and the variables correspond to the diseases that person has (1 = yes)

What I want is a dataframe with the proportion of people from the population who have and do not have each condition.

This is what I have done to generate the output I want:

1) Construct the proportion of the population which have each condition individually

```
Prop_cancer <- df %>%
group_by(cancer) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = round((count / sum(count))*100, digits = 1)) %>%
mutate(condition = "cancer") %>%
rename(Y_N = cancer) 

Prop_CVD <- df %>%
group_by(CVD) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = round((count / sum(count))*100, digits = 1)) %>%
mutate(condition = "CVD") %>%
rename(Y_N = CVD)

Prop_diab <- df %>%
group_by(diab) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = round((count / sum(count))*100, digits = 1)) %>%
mutate(condition = "diab") %>%
rename(Y_N = diab)

Prop_stroke <- df %>%
group_by(stroke) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = round((count / sum(count))*100, digits = 1)) %>%
mutate(condition = "stroke") %>%
rename(Y_N = stroke)

Prop_asthma <- df %>%
group_by(asthma) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = round((count / sum(count))*100, digits = 1)) %>%
mutate(condition = "asthma") %>%
rename(Y_N = asthma)
```

Add these all together

```
Prop_allcond <- bind_rows(Prop_cancer, Prop_CVD, Prop_stroke, Prop_diab, Prop_asthma)
```

I've got a large number of conditions, and a lot of data. Is there an easier / faster way to do this?

I considered creating a new variable 'condition' in the original dataframe, through an `ifelse` statement, but this does not allow a person to have more than one condition, and the conditions take precedence in the order I specify them.

Would be grateful for advice on how to simplify this code so that it's not so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse` we can use `gather` to collapse the dataframe into long format in `key`, `value` pairs then `group_by` them and count the ratio in each group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather() %>%
  group_by(key, value) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(freq = freq/sum(freq) * 100)


#   key    value  freq
#   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 CVD        0    70
# 2 CVD        1    30
# 3 asthma     0    80
# 4 asthma     1    20
# 5 cancer     0    80
# 6 cancer     1    20
# 7 diab       0    70
# 8 diab       1    30
# 9 stroke     0    60
#10 stroke     1    40
```

Note - I have ignored `LTC_count` column since that doesn't seem to be involved in the calculation.

---

Or we can reduce some steps by using `count` as suggested by @Jake Kaupp

```
df %>%
  gather() %>%
  count(key, value) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Percent population *with* a given disease:

```
colSums(df) / nrow(df) * 100
#cancer       CVD      diab    stroke    asthma LTC_count 
#20        30        30        40        20       150
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` this can be done in a single line, without gathering and whatnot:

```
df %>% summarize_at(vars(-LTC_count),funs(sum(.)/n()))
  cancer CVD diab stroke asthma
1    0.2 0.3  0.3    0.4    0.2
```

If we want both the yes and the no frequencies:

```
bind_rows("Y"=summarize_at(df,vars(-LTC_count),funs(sum(.)/n()*100)), 
  "N"=summarize_at(df,vars(-LTC_count),funs(sum(!.)/n()*100)),.id="id")

  id cancer CVD diab stroke asthma
1  Y     20  30   30     40     20
2  N     80  70   70     60     80
```

In response to your request for a long dataset, I could do the below, but frankly if you want this, you're better off with @Ronak's solultion:

```
df1<-bind_rows("Y"=summarize_at(df,vars(-LTC_count),funs(count=sum(.), freq=sum(.)/n()*100)), 
                 "N"=summarize_at(df,vars(-LTC_count),funs(count=sum(!.), freq=sum(!.)/n()*100)),.id="Y_N")

df1<-bind_cols(select(gather(df1,"condition","count",ends_with("_count")),-ends_with("freq")),
          select(gather(df1,"condition","freq",ends_with("_freq")),freq))[,c(2,3,4,1)]

df1$condition<-gsub("_count","",df1$condition)

   condition count freq Y_N
1     cancer     2   20   Y
2     cancer     8   80   N
3        CVD     3   30   Y
4        CVD     7   70   N
5       diab     3   30   Y
6       diab     7   70   N
7     stroke     4   40   Y
8     stroke     6   60   N
9     asthma     2   20   Y
10    asthma     8   80   N
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. This works great. But is it possible to have a long dataset whereby there is one column called "condition", another called "count", another called "freq", and the final one "Y_N"?

Comment: I created a solution based on this fulfilling your request, but frankly at this point @Ronak's solution makes more sense.